# Calling a javascript/jquery function inside div tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I want read a function return value into a div. I don't know how to achieve this in order to print text on UI.

Let say, I have these things below in one jsp

```
var textread = somejavascriptfunction(){ retrun somestring;}
```

Now, i want to pass this text to another jsp where i require this returned string.

In another Jsp,

```
<div><span>textread </span></div>
```

Can anyone help me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery's text function

```
$('span').text(textread);
```

Comment: So, it read the text to div spam element? Am i right?How is passing this from one jsp to another jsp?Basically my textread in another JSP

Comment: javascript works on the rendered page so the jsp files are converted to html, and the text function writes the value of textread to the span